# Taking periodic thread dumps on JVM - ThreadMXBean vs JVMTI agent

Tags: java, performance, monitoring, jmx, jvmti

I am trying to build a system that takes periodic thread dumps on JVM processes so that they can be analyzed later in case of issues. I intent to cause minimum overhead to JVM while taking thread dumps. There are multiple ways for taking thread dumps and I have finally shortlisted 2 options - Either building a custom JVMTI agent or using ThreadMXBean. I was wondering is somebody has done an analysis on which approach would result in least JVM overhead? Or do they cause the same overhead?

Comment: `ThreadMXBean` is the worst way to get thread dumps. It builds Java-level representation of stack traces, that's why it is slow and creates lots of garbage in the heap. JVMTI is a way better. However, even better is to ask JVM to make stack traces for you (see the linked answer).

Comment: Thanks for linking the question. Asking the JVM means waitibg for safe point, which in my (profiling) use case, not required. I have actually started looking at using perf tools or DTrace.

Comment: If the primary purpose of stack traces is CPU profiling, than you might want to paraphrase the question. In the current form the question is indeed already answered.

Comment: As to profiling, I can recommend [this post](http://techblog.netflix.com/2015/07/java-in-flames.html).

Comment: Thanks. Really useful.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on your desired frequency of sampling, but in most cases it will have some impact and results will be biased. If you're up for JVMTI though, definitely take a look at Honest Profiler: https://github.com/RichardWarburton/honest-profiler

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know about safe points and AsyncGetCallTrace. This will be very useful for my research.

Comment: `AsyncGetCallTrace` is good for profiling. However, it does not create thread dumps. I.e. `AsyncGetCallTrace` can get you a nice trace of an **active** thread, but it won't give a picture of all threads.

Comment: Agreed. My use case is mostly for profiling needs rather than getting a view of what all threads are doing at a particular instant.